# oracle utl_file different encoding

Tags: oracle, utl-file

I have a stored procedure that reads a table then exports those records in a file

These files must be encoded in **UTF-8 (without BOM) and Line feed**.. **not CR**
but sometimes are encoded in ASCII, so I get warnings..

Here's the procedure

```
    BEGIN
            l_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR(C_DIRECTORY_PATH, l_tmp_file_name, 'A', 32767); 
            UTL_FILE.PUTF_NCHAR(l_file, l_head || '\n');
      FOR table IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE_1)
      LOOP
           l_rec  := '"' || table.field1 || '"' || table.field2 || ... -- a lot of fields
           UTL_FILE.PUTF_NCHAR (l_file, l_rec || '\n');
           UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(l_file);

      END LOOP;

      UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(l_file);
      UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(l_file);

  END;
```

So to check if files are encoded in UTF...I run file filename 
and I get values like:

```
 UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
 UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
 ASCII text, with very long lines
```

It's random despite I'm expecting UTF-8..

the instance of db is running on **redhat distro**
WE8MSWIN1252 (NLS DB()

*Why I'm using UTL_FILE.FOPEN_N_CHAR?*

> ‘...the contents of the file are always read and written in UTF8’

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_file.htm#BABDEJDH

*Why PUTF_NCHAR?*

> 'Formatted text is written in the UTF8 character set to the file
>   identified by the file handle'

Comment: Did you try `UTL_FILE.PUTF_NCHAR (l_file, l_rec || CHR(10));`?

Comment: What is your database character set? In case of UTF-8 (`AL32UTF8`) you can also use `UTL_FILE.PUT`, resp `UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE`

Comment: Does your table data contain any special characters? Note, **every** ASCII encoded file is also an UTF-8 file since ASCII is a strict subset of UTF-8

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit data contains like accents, so yes..special character i'd say

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit WE8MSWIN1252